# 3D Touch Peek and Pop from UITableViewCell how to hand over data to other UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, 3dtouch

my app stores different attributes in Core Data objects. They are all shown in a UITableView, if you click a cell, a DetailView is shown. the usual stuff like in the Master-Detail-XCode-Template.

Now I want to implement 3D Touch with peek and pop. Like in the Mail app, 3D touch a cell, get preview, press deeper, pop in the detail.

I got this working so far, but I can t figure out how to pass the corresponding data in

```
- (nullable UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id <UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location
```

and

```
- (void)previewingContext:(id <UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext commitViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToCommit
```

to the other DetailViewController.

If you just click the cell (no 3D touch) I hand over the data in

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
```

I am using a

```
id detailItem
```

in every ViewController and I set the corresponding object to it.

So I try to get something similar to work, so in my DetailViewController my "detailItem" needs the corresponding Core Data object from the selected (3D touched) cell.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the destination View controller from the storyboard using its storyboard ID and pass the objects that you are doing in prepareForSegue method.

Below is the code that I use to pass the data. Its in Swift, it should be similar in objective C. Let me know if you want Objective C version.

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing,viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? method:

    // Obtain the index path and the cell that was pressed.
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location),
              cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) else { return nil }

    // Create a destination view controller and set its properties.
    guard let destinationViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DestinationViewController") as? DestinationViewController else { return nil }
    let object = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    destinationViewController.detailItem = object

    /*
        Set the height of the preview by setting the preferred content size of the destination view controller. Height: 0.0 to get default height
    */
    destinationViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)

    previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame

    return destinationViewController
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was really close but messed something up ... ;)

Comment: @Dheeraj Dir sir you did not mention that you took this piece of code from apple. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ViewControllerPreviews/Listings/Projects_PreviewUsingDelegate_PreviewUsingDelegate_MasterViewController_UIViewControllerPreviewing_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016546-Projects_PreviewUsingDelegate_PreviewUsingDelegate_MasterViewController_UIViewControllerPreviewing_swift-DontLinkElementID_6

Comment: guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location),
              cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) else { return nil }
This method is giving the wrong index.
Is there any way to get tapped view using 3D touch?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using storyboard segues from the cell to the new view controller, the sender is the table view cell.

So you could implement `prepareForSegue:` as such:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        id viewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        // Get your data object
        // Pass it to the new view controller
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Base on Dheeraj's reply, adjust some code to rectify the wrong touch location of tableview cell. Assume we need pass the value named type to destination controller.

```
- (nullable UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id <UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location{
// check if we're not already displaying a preview controller
if ([self.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]]) {
    return nil;
}

CGPoint cellPostion = [self.tableview convertPoint:location fromView:self.view];
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:cellPostion];

if (path) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    type = [[self.data objectAtIndex:path.row] integerValue];
    // shallow press: return the preview controller here (peek)
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    DetailViewController *previewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
    previewController.type = type;
    previewingContext.sourceRect = [self.view convertRect:cell.frame fromView:self.tableview];
    return previewController;
}
return nil;
```

}

Comment: Just call [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:self.tableView] somewhere like viewDidLoad to make [self.tableview convertPoint:location fromView:self.view] call not necessary. Conversion will be done for you by UIKit.

Comment: There is a problem while using `[self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:self.tableView]`. That is the snapshot of the 3d touch animation is not including `contentView.transform` state. Let's say you set `contentView.transform = TransformHelper.reverse()` to each cell, then you'll end up with upside down cell s while the 3d touch animation is running.