# How to register for previewing single cell under 3D Touch?

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

Currently I have the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
        registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: tableView)
    }
}
```

The point is that in this case blurred is everything out of `UITableView` instead of everything out of that one specific `UITableViewCell`.

How can I expose only one cell?

The state of this image in during forcing 3d touch.
[image]

Comment: I think this answer could help you : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002637/3d-touch-peek-and-pop-from-uitableviewcell-how-to-hand-over-data-to-other-uiview>

Answer (score 0):

This should be in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
    registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: tableView)
}
```

Then in `previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint)` add this:

```
guard let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else { return nil }
previewingContext.sourceRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: selectedIndexPath)
```

Answer (score -1):

You did right, you do need to register for previewing in the `viewDidLoad`
.
Although, you also need to implement the `previewingContext` method, to provide a source rect. Basically, you'll give the cell as the source rect, and everything outside of it will become blurry.

Please checkout this [Peek and Pop tutorial](http://blog.prolificinteractive.com/2015/12/09/3d-touch-behind-the-scenes-the-peek-and-pop-tutorial/) for more details.

You can also checkout [the sample of code](https://github.com/quentinR/PI3DTouch)

Comment: he means **CELL**