# how to detect index path of a collection view while using 3d touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, 3dtouch

I am working on ios app in that i want to implement 3d touch peak and pop in my collection view.for that i am using the below code

how to detect index path of a collection view while using 3d touch using objectiveC?

Comment: It doesn't call `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` or `collectionView:didHighlightItemAtAtIndexPath:`? Or according to this (https://engineering.instagram.com/posts/465414923641286/lessons-learned-with-3D-touch), it should call `previewingContext:viewControllerForLocation:`. Then you can retrieve the point: `UICollectionView *collectionView = (UICollectionView *)[previewingContext sourceView]; NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];`

Comment: Or look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002637/3d-touch-peek-and-pop-from-uitableviewcell-how-to-hand-over-data-to-other-uiview It's almost the same system between UICollectionView and UITableView do find the `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: Thanks a lot large for your valuable time and comment when i used the both code the app crashing.

Comment: If it crash, there should be an error message.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me after adding this line in did load  [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:self.collectionview];